# My material UI custom classes are being overridden by material UI's default classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a TextField whose label I want to be colored as black when it is focused. I added the classes to InputProps with that classes variable but unfortunately, it is being overridden by material UI's default styling in chrome dev tools. Here is the code. Please check the screenshot of chrome dev tools.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
inputLabelFocused: {
color: "black",
 },
}));

const classes = useStyles();

<TextField
      id="toDo"
      label="To Do"
      multiline
      rows={4}
      variant="filled"
      fullWidth
      InputLabelProps={{
        classes: {
          focused: classes.inputLabelFocused,
        },
      }}
    />
```

[image of custom classes being overridden by default material UI classes in chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk6dQ.png)

Comment: Sounds like it's not just you - [github issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/25324)

Comment: It also sounds like you should check to make sure you're importing your themeprovider/makeStyles/etc all from the same package - @material-ui/core/styles OR @material-ui/styles, but DO NOT mix these: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/25324#issuecomment-871311851 (but in general, the issue seems active, despite being closed) - are you using NextJS?

Comment: I am importing everything including makeStyles and TextField from @material-ui/core. No I'm am not using next.js. plain react.

Comment: Is anywhere else in this entire application importing from @material-ui/styles? The GitHub issue says it's been a common problem reported for years, that most of the time has been developer error (e.g. multiple packages of @material-ui/styles). Try to blow away your node_modules (and even package-lock or yarn.lock) and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  inputLabelFocused: {
    color: "black !important",
  },
});
```

Comment: I get the usage of !important but why exactly is material  ui not implementing custom styles when that's exactly what the "classes" variable is supposed to do.